# C# reading from a network stream without an ending character

Tags: c#, networking, networkstream

I'm trying to read a line from a network stream that has now line return at the end.
This line could be anything but will always end without a line return.

Currently I'm doing

```
string line4 = sr.readline();
```

But this just halts my code, even though I've given it everything I want it to read.

Is there a way to read this final line without the return character?

Comment: You need to check if `stream.DataAvailable` or set a read timeout. StreamReader will advance `bufferLength` bytes repeatedly until it finds a \r\n (or 0x10 0x13), then it will return everything up to that point and start caching for the next "line". If there is no data avalable or the StreamReader detects that we reached end of stream then it returns null.
So checking if your line is null one OK way to check that your stream ended.
But in reality it depends too much on what kind of protocol your working with on that stream.

Comment: Don't waste your time on `DataAvailable`. You should be using async I/O, which means nothing is blocked anyway as long as there's no data. As far as the missing endline (CR, LF, or CR/LF...whatever), if you don't want to close the connection at the end of that line, the sender _must_ provide the endline. But, if they are done sending, then they should call `Socket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send)` to indicate that they are done sending. Then `StreamReader.ReadLine()` will terminate normally (i.e. return `null` to indicate end-of-stream after returning that last endline-less line).

Comment: This comment from @Felype is wrong: _"If there is no data avalable...then it returns null"_. That happens _only_ at end-of-stream. If data is simply not available, then `StreamReader` blocks. Unless of course you use async read (e.g. `ReadLineAsync()`), in which case it returns the awaitable in an incompleted state.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorted it out now. Cheers